# CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found with DigiCert certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, devops

**Given:**

1. Android devices from different vendors, all in India. All OS versions (from `Android 5` to `Android 14`) There are more than a hundred different devices in total, here are the first ten models:

   ```
   M2010J19SI
   CPH2579
   MT2111
   SM-M315F
   220733SI
   CPH2139
   CPH1933
   EB2101
   RMX3780
   ```
2. Server with a paid certificate for TLS - `DigiCert Global Root G2` (https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm)
3. An application that sends network requests from devices to the server using `OkHttp` library.

**Problem:**

The specified devices, judging by the information that we collect programmatically, cannot reach the server due to an `SSL` error.

In the statistics collection system we see errors of the following type:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.


Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.


Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

**Assumption:**

The devices do not have the required certificate in the list of trusted system certificates.

**Confirmation of assumption:**

1. We take any device/emulator
2. We disable the certificate in its settings (on the emulator, disable it here: `Settings->Security->Encryption&Credentials->Trusted credentials`) - see screenshot.

   [image]
3. We try to send a network request - we receive an error similar to that observed in the error collection system.
4. Manually embed the disabled certificate into the application like this:

- add the certificate file (`digi_cert_global_cag2`) to `res/raw`
- create a `network_security_config` file in `res/xml` with the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/digi_cert_global_cag2" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

- we write the config in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <application
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
```

5. Network requests are now sent successfully.

**Problem:**

1. Manually embedding a certificate into the application did not solve the problem - the specified devices continue to generate an `SSL` error, as our error collection system tells us.
2. There is no device on which the problem can be reproduced without manually disabling the certificate.

**Inappropriate solutions:**

Using a regular LetsEnctypt certificate is not an option, because a paid certificate is required at the request of third parties.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone encountered this?
2. What to do?

<s>Ignoring this error (happens to an extremely small number of users) is also not an option - DevOps is strongly against it</s>

Comment: I assume the typo in your posted network_security_config is just a copy and paste problem? the second quote of cleartextTrafficPermitted is totally misplaced. That type of Android devices are you talking about, e.g. which Android version is running on them? The network security config way requires Android 7+. What HTTP class/library do you use?

Comment: @Robert yes, copy-paste problem, fixed) Also I've added info about OS version (all versions suffers - from Android 5 to 14) and about networking library - it's `OkHttp`, nothing special

Comment: Are you sure the HTPS config of the server is correct? Having so many different devices affected makes a TLS config problem more than likely. Check the server using e.g. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ My guess is that the server does not correctly send the full certificate chain, thus an intermediate cert is missing. The devices that work have this intermediate cert installed or got it from somewhere else.